# How to install .NET Core with a .NET Framework C# script?

Tags: c#, .net

To make distribution of my `.NET Core` app easier, I wish to bundle the installer for it in my installation process and silently install it together with my application. Windows already comes with the `.NET Framework` so it should be possible to write a .NET script that does this.

I tried to use a provided PS script: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-install-script but sadly even after successfully running it and finishing without errors the `dotnet` command was not found. I manually added to PATH `C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Microsoft\dotnet` but it seems that was not enough.

Has something like this been done before? What exactly does the official .NET Core installer does besides putting files in `\AppData\Local\Microsoft\dotnet` and setting environment variables? I am using `NSIS` for my installer.

Comment: Perhaps you can use Self-Contained Deployment? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/#self-contained-deployments-scd

Comment: Definitely use a self contained app rather than forcing users to install a specific version of the runtime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You see, having to install anything onto a system sounds like pain, when .net core actually allows you to bundle everything your app needs (and only that, I believe) as the comments above suggest.

In spirit of Keeping It Stupidly Simple I would suggest you consider that option and not reinvent the wheel here.

I feel like I am hijacking an answer here, but here's the documentation and I believe all you need to do is add one command line to your build:

```
dotnet publish -c Release -r <RID> --self-contained true
```

For more inspiration see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/#self-contained-deployments-scd

For the sake of completeness I'll suggest you check out [Chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/) as it's basically a package manager for Windows that you can run pretty easily. But again, I'd advise you against writing custom scripts when Microsoft has already taken care of it.

Comment: This is a better answer, I'll leave mine for info, but given the OP description this is more suitable

Comment: Self contained is actually the default now with .NET Core 3.0 and above.

Comment: Thank you. I did as suggest and it worked, albeit it increased my program by 150MB. Do you know how to change this setting inside Rider IDE? I did it within command line but am unable to find Rider settings.

Comment: Good stuff. 150Mb is actually pretty modest given the packaged installer of .net Core 3.0 runtime is about 140Mb (and that's packaged). I'm unfortunately not familiar with Rider so probably won't be able to give you a definitive answer. Since this is a project setting rather than IDE, I suspect you should be able to achieve this by changing settings in your project files even if UI does not allow you to. (you'll have to look up the documentation to see where exactly though)

Answer (score 0):

You can get inspiration from a .NET tool I co-wrote with Joseph Woodward here: https://github.com/JosephWoodward/DotNetInstallSdkGlobalTool/tree/master/src/DotNetInstallSdk

The technique we used was to download the release metadata json ([Blogged here](https://stu.dev/a-look-at-jsondocument/)) and then download and run the appropriate installer for the platform and version.

**Edit:** Others have pointed out the self-contain deployment option, this is more suitable for the problem you are trying to solve.